# Shiny App - Saving an input entry as variable and use it in the code

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm working on Shiny App and I need to save a numeric input ("num") as a variable and use it in a ifelse statement.

I tried for example to do `myvalue <- input$num` inside the server function but it does not work.

I need to do this with at leat other 4 or five inputs.

Anybody has ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: just use `input$num` everywhere you would `myvalue`. This is not a problem.

Option 2: use a `reactive()`. Note the parentheses `myvalue()`, call it like you would a function. (This *is* a function).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", "Number", 0),
  textOutput("positive"),
  textOutput("odd")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Option 1
  output$positive <- renderText({
    if (input$num >= 0) {
      "Positive number."
    } else {
      "Negative number."
    }
  })

  # Option 2
  myvalue <- reactive({
    input$num
  })

  output$odd <- renderText({
    if (myvalue() %% 1 != 0) {
      "Not an integer."
    } else if (myvalue() %% 2 == 0) {
      "Even number."
    } else {
      "Odd number."
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 5 inputs and need to insert them as parameters in a function I have created. And then print the result of the function. Any ideas how?